# Remove stopwords from BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a large list of comments from reddit. The strings are split into words, punctuation removed, and quantified to show the most used words on a particular subreddit:

```
SELECT word, COUNT(*) as num_words
FROM(FLATTEN((
  SELECT SPLIT(LOWER(REGEXP_REPLACE(body, r'[\.\",*:()\[\]/|\n]', ' ')), ' ') word
  FROM [fh-bigquery:reddit_comments.2017_08]
  WHERE subreddit="The_Donald"
  ), word))
GROUP EACH BY word
HAVING num_words >= 1000
ORDER BY num_words DESC
```

I have a list of stopwords to remove, how would I go about adding that to the code? Thanks :)

Comment: In case you want to make your own stopword lists: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47058865/132438

Answer (score 5):

Below example is for BigQuery Legacy SQL (as it is in your question)

```sql
#legacydSQL
SELECT word, COUNT(*) AS num_words
FROM(FLATTEN((
  SELECT SPLIT(LOWER(REGEXP_REPLACE(body, r'[\.\",*:()\[\]/|\n]', ' ')), ' ') word
  FROM [fh-bigquery:reddit_comments.2017_08]
  WHERE subreddit="The_Donald"
  ), word))
WHERE NOT word IN (
  'the','to','a','and'
)
GROUP EACH BY word
HAVING num_words >= 1000
ORDER BY num_words DESC
```

BigQuery Team strongly recommends using Standard SQL
So if you will decide to [`migrate`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/migrating-from-legacy-sql)  - below is example in Standard SQL
It assumes you have your stop words in `your_project.your_dataset.stop_words` table

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT word, COUNT(*) AS num_words
FROM `fh-bigquery.reddit_comments.2017_08`,
UNNEST(SPLIT(LOWER(REGEXP_REPLACE(body, r'[\.\",*:()\[\]/|\n]', ' ')), ' ')) word
WHERE subreddit="The_Donald"
AND word NOT IN (SELECT stop_word FROM `your_project.your_dataset.stop_words`)
GROUP BY word
HAVING num_words >= 1000
AND word != ''
ORDER BY num_words DESC
```

You can test / play with below dummy data here

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `your_project.your_dataset.stop_words` AS (
  SELECT stop_word 
  FROM UNNEST(['the','to','a','and']) stop_word
)
SELECT word, COUNT(*) AS num_words
FROM `fh-bigquery.reddit_comments.2017_08`,
UNNEST(SPLIT(LOWER(REGEXP_REPLACE(body, r'[\.\",*:()\[\]/|\n]', ' ')), ' ')) word
WHERE subreddit="The_Donald"
AND word NOT IN (SELECT stop_word FROM `your_project.your_dataset.stop_words`)
GROUP BY word
HAVING num_words >= 1000
AND word != ''
ORDER BY num_words DESC
```